# If batch file is closed, other program is closed as well

Tags: windows, batch-file, process

I have a batch file that runs an old game, fixing a lot of issues that the game had. Long story short, the batch file stays open while the game is running, and if the batch file gets closed before the game gets closed, then it screws up a bunch of stuff in the game. Is there any way to set it so if the batch file is closed, it ends another process (the game's process)?

It is fine if I have to keep another batch file running to start the original batch, starting the game. Here's a more visual representation of what I expect to achieve:

Batch1 - starts batch2, ends Process1 if batch2 gets closed

Batch2 - starts Process1

Process1 - (game)

I already have batch2 coded to my liking, I just need help with batch1. Any ideas of what it would look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this approach **[NOT TESTED]** :

From batch1.bat, call batch2.bat and wait for it to terminate. Once it is terminated, use **TASKKILL** to kill the process associated with your game.

```
start /wait cmd /k CALL "path to batch2.bat"
TASKKILL /F /IM processName.exe
```

Comment: It works! Kind of...it says "^CTerminate Batch Job? <Y/N>" and if I type N and hit enter, it works. Any way to make this step automatic?

Comment: you can use **< nul** after the start command. Refer to this link for more details: http://superuser.com/questions/35698/how-to-supress-terminate-batch-job-y-n-confirmation/35741#35741

Comment: hmm...that didn't work...where exactly would i put < nul? I tried a bunch of different locations

Comment: < nul should be used like:  start /wait cmd /k CALL "path to batch2.bat" < nul . I haven't used it but answers in the link mention that < nul would suppress the (Y/N) prompt.

Comment: hmm yeah i tried that and it doesn't work :/ O well this got me some progress! thanks